# how to change database folder on wamp server

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

I created database on wamp server and tried to find it in "www" folder, but i didn't found it there, instead the database folder was located in "wamp64/bin/mysql/data". 
How can i change the dirctory of databases to "www" folder.

I have tried altering the htdocs file but it didnt help. I tried both xampp and wamp servers, but still they gave me the same problem.

Comment: If you want to change folder you need to install mysql to other location, not best idea if you only started with php, and not sure if it's good to put database files to publicly available place so others can access them

Comment: @MarekMaszay You dont need to install mysql in another location to move the database locations

Comment: You do not want to move your databases to the www folder. There is no need to do that. Why do you think you want to do this? Remember MySQL is not like Access. MySQL is a proper DBMS

Comment: ya, but i didn't want to make the databases public. i just want them to be created on the default folders "htdocs" or "www". i am watching a video tutorial about creating login page, and on the tutorial after he create database he found it on the default folder " htdocs" then he started saving the web files on that folder.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are either getting confused, or watching a very BAD Tutorial

Comment: You do not have direct access to a MySQL database. You call functions in PHP that connect you to MySQL, you then pass that a query, BUT IT'S MYSQL that does all the work and only it needs to know where the actual database lives